# what are these? devpts proc sysfs...?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I'm building my first Linux from scratch... now I've reached a point to mount some filesystems that I don't know what they are and what they're meant to do...!
these are the commands that I'm gonna use:

```
mount -vt devpts devpts $LFS/dev/pts
mount -vt proc proc $LFS/proc
mount -vt sysfs sysfs $LFS/sys
mount -vt tmpfs shm $LFS/dev/shm
```

could somebody explain them to me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all virtual filesystems, in the sense they don't exist anywhere in a physical disk, and are only file-based representations of data stored in the RAM (remember that [everything is a file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file) on UNIX-like systems).

- [/dev/pts](https://www.nsa.gov/research/_files/selinux/papers/slinux/node60.shtml): contains pseudo terminal devices (that's why Konsole, GNOME Terminal, etc. are terminal *emulators*)
- [/proc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) and [/sys](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob_plain;f=Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt;hb=HEAD): exposes kernel's data structures to the userspace (/proc: mainly process-related stuff; /sys: devices, drivers and kernel settings)
- [/dev/shm](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/what-is-devshm-and-its-practical-usage.html): provides file-based shared memory (basically a RAM disk)

Comment: where are these files before being mounted? I mean for example when we wanna mount a usb flash drive on a directory we point to a file (for example sdb2) in /dev representing the flash drive but in the mentioned mount commands we are pointing at nowhere (directly to a file that does not exist) !

Comment: @morTie That's right. On these cases, it's not the files that matter, but the filesystems. I think you can use `none` as the filename, if it makes things clearer for you.

Comment: Oops..! my mistake sorry... you are totally right :D